# Solving ODE in physical context (barometric formula)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was tempted to ask this in physics channel but since it appears to me to be a downright math problem:

It's just an ODE with some physics symbols:

$$\frac{\mathrm{dp(h)}}{\mathrm{dh}} = -\frac{g}{\mathrm{R_s}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{p(h)}}{\mathrm{T(h)}}$$
What might be easily solved by separations of variables. It's just bothering me that $\mathrm{T(h)}$ is dependent of $\mathrm{h}$:

$\mathrm{T(h)} = \mathrm{T_0}-\alpha(\mathrm{h-h_0})$. How do I deal with that? Do I sub it in?

$$\frac{\mathrm{dp(h)}}{\mathrm{dh}} = -\frac{g}{\mathrm{R_s}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{p(h)}}{ \mathrm{T_0}-\alpha(\mathrm{h-h_0})}$$

Solving this ODE yields: $$\mathrm{p(h)}=C_{1}\,{\mathrm{e}}^{\dfrac{g\,\ln\left(\alpha\,h-T_{0}-\alpha\,h_{0}\right)}{\mathrm{Rs}\,\alpha}}$$

Physically this seems strange to my because the exponential is not decaying (what's actually characteristic for pressure in higher heights).

Comment: The solution actually counts for the one with $-$-sign. I just forgot to add it before. So, I'm still confused.

Comment: I guess the solution was all the time right, it was just about interpretation: you can rewrite $\mathrm{p(h)} = C_1\cdot e^{\dfrac{g}{R_s\,\alpha}}\cdot e^{\displaystyle{\ln(T_0-\alpha(h-h_0))}} = C_1\cdot(T_0-\alpha(h-h_0))\cdot e^{\dfrac{g}{R_s\,\alpha}}$

Comment: That's proving: it's dropping with higher heights (constant minus negative)

Comment: What you wrote in the question is indeed wrong, the $h$ in the log should end up having a minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $\frac{dp}{dh}=C \frac{p}{T}$ where $C<0,T>0$ then you have $\frac{dp}{p}=C \frac{dh}{T}$ so $\ln(p(h)/p(h_0))=C \int_{h_0}^h \frac{dh}{T}$. Now if $h>h_0$ then the RHS of this equation is negative, so $p(h)<p(h_0)$ as expected. (The nice thing about this way of looking at it is that the actual form of $T(h)$ doesn't matter at all, you just need it to be positive.)

If you actually expand on what $T$ is in this situation, you have $\int_{h_0}^h \frac{dh}{T_0-\alpha(h-h_0)} = -\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{T_0}^T \frac{dT'}{T'} = -\frac{1}{\alpha} \ln(T/T_0)$. So you have $\frac{p}{p_0}=e^{-\frac{C}{\alpha} \ln(T/T_0)}$. As a sanity check, as $h$ increases, $T$ decreases, so the log becomes more negative, so the entire exponent becomes more negative, i.e. $p$ decreases.